# How to get value from ejs to node js file

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

This is the value i used to input data using ejs

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/">
<input type="text" name="user[name]">
<input type="text" name="user[email]">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the node js code

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app     = express();
  var bodyParser = require("body-parser")

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
 }));

app.post('/', function(request, response){

console.log(request.body.user.name);
console.log(request.body.user.email);

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

when i run this there is no error but page not load? can anyone give me solution.

Comment: Is this all the code? You need to render the view to display it, you also need to set the renderer to EJS. See https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application for more information about setting up Node for EJS.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from `user[name]` `user[email]` to `name` `email` and in server `request.body.name` `request.body.email`.